# How do I jump/toggle to a closing bracket in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know some shortcut to jump to a closing bracket in PhpStorm (IntelliJ - JetBrains)?

I'm trying to find other ways to do this without using the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl + ]</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + [</kbd>.

I would like a shortcut **to toggle** to matching braces in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu bar, go to "Navigate/ Navigate in File/ Move Caret to Matching Brace". You probably want to memorise the keyboard shortcut displayed there.

Another way to find the command is "Help/ Find Action". It can take a bit of guessing, though, if you don't know the right keywords.

[image: Find actions dialogue with "matchi" typed in the search box]

Note that "Find Action" itself also has a keyboard shortcut, and you can also tap <kbd>Shift</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd> (double shift) to get the "Find All" tab of this same dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut to toggle:

> **Ctrl + Shit + M** for Windows

> **Ctrl + M** for Mac

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts can differ base don the keymap used. It makes no sense to mention every single keymap. But you can provide an action name instead. This way the person can find what that shortcut is on his computer and add/adjust it if needed. Consider adding that info.